# Как определить родительское окно контрола

Tags: wpf, winforms

Допустим есть окно, в окне у нас есть контрол. Если взять контрол, то по нему можно определить его главного родителя - окно, следующей функцией :

```
        var window = Window.GetWindow(control);
```

Так как у нас в WPF есть замечательное `VisualTree` по которому можно ходить влево право вверх и вниз.

Но мы не ищем легких путей, бородатый легаси проект написанный на WinForms дополняется функционалом на WPF.

И у нас есть Tab на winforms внутри которого UserControl WPF'овский. Очевидно что `GetWindow` не сработает. Как можно определить родительское окно? Очень необходимо для реализации behavior'a. Предположение такое - пробиться в самый верх - UserControl и попробовать у него взять его холдера и дальше методами Winforms взять родительское окно.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал идти вверх по визуальному дереву при помощи `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent` до верха. Это должно дать UserControl верхнего уровня. Но я не знаю, как из него получить WinForms-контрол.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала думал копать в сторону `WinApi`,но отказался от это идеи, ибо мне необходимо было ловить события от родительской формы, а делать `AddHook` `RemoveHook` и обрабатывать, через огромный `case` что мне надо - не оптимально и может запутать следующего погромиста который откроет код.

В дебрях интернета и StackOverFlov'a было найдено решение :

```
var src = (HwndSource) PresentationSource.FromDependencyObject(_primitive);
var hst = (System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost)System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromChildHandle(src.Handle);
var formChild = hst.TopLevelControl;
var form = formChild.FindForm();
```

Работает, просто и лаконично - в 4 строки, а не в кучу строк с определением дескриптора окна и обработки сообщений.